# Error with Go modules build using /cmd structure

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm new to go modules, and am taking them for a spin in a new project which I'm trying to model after the structure described [here](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout)

Here is an example of my directory structure:

```
.
├── cmd
│   └── app_name
│       └── main.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── internal
│   └── bot
│       └── bot.go
└── pkg
    ├── website_name
    │   ├── client.go
    │   ├── client.options.go
    │   ├── server.go
    │   └── server.options.go
    └── lib
        └── lib.go
```

1. Is this idiomatically correct? I know there's not a whole lot of consensus out there, but I'd like to follow best practices.
2. When I run `go build` I get 'unexpected module path "github.com/ragurney/app_name/cmd/app_name"', but when I run `go build ./...` it works. Why?

When I move `main.go` to the top level everything works as expected. Should I just not use the `/cmd` pattern with modules?

Comment: What is the `module` line in your go.mod? It sounds like it's referring to `cmd/app_name` which would be incorrect - it should point at the directory where it is located.

Comment: It was pointing to `cmd/app_name` specifically:
`module github.com/ragurney/app_name/cmd/app_name`. So instead it should be: `github.com/ragurney/app_name`? Doing that causes a similar error: "cannot find module providing package github.com/ragurney/app_name"

Comment: Yes, it should be `github.com/ragurney/app_name` if that's the root (where the go.mod file is). Do you have multiple `go.mod` files in your repo by chance?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer your first question, its completely opinionated and whatever you like best that is also easy to understand for others you should go with (I think it's fine).

To answer your second question the reason `go build ./...` works as opposed to `go build` from the root directory is because `./...` starts in the current directory (the root) and searches for all program entry-points and builds them. When you move `main.go` to the root directory, with this new information, `go build` working then makes sense, as its only looking in the current directory.

You can explicitly say `go build ./cmd/app_name` which would also work.

Your application structure works perfectly fine with modules, as I use something very similar to it (https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/02/package-oriented-design.html) and modules work very well for me.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, also for the link that's a pretty helpful resource! Just to confirm, it's fine if I keep this structure, and then I'd init with `go mod init github.com/ragurney/app_name`? Then whenever I want to generate the binary, run `go build cmd/app_name/main.go`?

Comment: Yes that's perfectly valid!

Comment: As the answer says, you would `go build ./cmd/app_name`. You build a *package*, not a *file*, and it's important to root it in CWD (otherwise go thinks you're giving a package name, not a path).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for all the help everyone and for putting up with my noobish questions. Learned some new things today :D

Comment: "...it's important to root it in CWD..."

@Adrian can you point me to a link that describes that / elaborate a little more? I've done `go mod init github.com/ragurney/app_name` which seems to be working fine, although my cwd is something along the lines of `/Users/rygurney/Code/OtherDir/app_name`

Comment: `go help build` would explain what I was talking about in my comment, but it's nothing to do with modules, it's just how the build command works.

Answer (score 0):

from what i can tell there is nothing wrong with your project structure. What has worked for me is to run the go build/run command from the project root

eg.
`go run github.com/username/project/cmd/somecommand`

`go build -o somebinary github.com/username/project/cmd/somecommand`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to add the specific file to build, there are some projects with more than one executable

`go build -o app ./cmd/server/main.go`